# Offset in Bootstrap is not working.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, offset

SO I'm dusting up on bootstrap atm, and decided as a practice to create some grids with offsets.

I have no idea what's going on.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3
</div>
   <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
```

These should make it three rows, first with a space in between the div's, etc
but it's just not working.

Any elucidation as to why would be appreciated. I append codepen link below.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgXPae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
```

Comment: No problem, click the check below the arrows if it worked for you, to indicate that the answer is correct, any problem call me.

Answer (score 0):

it should be col-md-offset-3
you can see the documentation of grid in this link

[offsets][1]http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid